# How to put image on top of another image?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following XML code that I use for creating (dynamically) the avatar image:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/users_avatar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp" />
```

It creates:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out a way of adding a small green circled tick icon like so:

[image]

What would be the easiest way to do it?

**EDIT**: I have created the green circled tick drawable.
How do I put it on top of the avatar if the size of the avatar is `50dp` (width and height)? I wrapped the two `ImageViews` in `RelativeLayout` and tried to play with margin and padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileImage"
            app:civ_border_color="#000"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dishu" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/check" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

> @drawable/check

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="#4CAF50">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM10,17l-5,-5 1.41,-1.41L10,14.17l7.59,-7.59L19,8l-9,9z"/>
</vector>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: When your code answer uses a 3rd party library, you should also provide its link as well with the answer to make it more understandable..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Constraint layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#252525"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        />
    <View
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/remove_watchlist"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Android studio design screenshot]